# Grails clean leaves java process

Tags: java, grails

I am using Grails 2.3.5, I think this might be a bug in this version of grails. Whenever I execute `clean` command from my `STS` that have grails suite installed it leaves a java.exe background task.

I know `grails clean` is a jvm process but this should be terminated when when `grails clean` finishes cleaning but it stays there forever instead wasting my ~250 MB memory.

Before executing `clean` No of java processes : 1 (ie STS)
After executing `clean` No of java processes : 2 (STS and clean)

And whenever I kill that process, everything stays same.

Testes OSs:
Win8 (jvm7)
Ubuntu13.10 (jvm7)

Comment: any more information you can provide? like whats the command line for the process? (ps -ef will tell you that on linux)

Comment: Does this happen on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: Using windows right now! sry

Comment: @chrylis Yes! Actually I don't trust linux very much But I am surprised to see it on windows too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grails 2.3 there was the addition of [forked execution](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode), there is the option to use a daemon to help start up time of grails. If you comment out all of the forked mode config that may fix your issue.